# How can I execute a method before Blazor Server shutdown?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

My program must execute a method called `Checksum()` before application shutdown because when the application run again must validate the checksum to continue. If the method doesn't run before the application shutdown, the changes on the database will not be noticed.

I tried with `Circuit` but that isn't what I need. It runs the method when a user closes the connection with the server but not when the server shuts down.

I tried with `IHostApplicationLifetime` but that also doesn't work. I also tried with `IApplicationLifetime`, and wasn't able to do what I wanted to.

I tried all these in the BlazorServer `Program.cs` and I put breakpoints.

I haven't found good information on it. Probably the way that I implemented the `IApplicationLifetime` or `IHostApplicationLifetime` was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer.

using `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService` Program.cs:

```
public class Program: IHostedService
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
  }

  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
          {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
          });

  public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      //RUN A METHOD ON APPLICATION START
  }

  public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      //RUN A METHOD ON APPLICATION STOP
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHostedService<Program>(); //ADD THIS
}
```

I found it here: [LINK](https://andrewlock.net/extending-the-shutdown-timeout-setting-to-ensure-graceful-ihostedservice-shutdown/)

Comment: You de  realize this is not very reliable or useful for a WebHost?  It looks more useful for background services that have a 'deterministic ending'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  I understand. I need it to end the background threads and processes. I have a lot of processes running and  each is updating the database constantly. So I should end with all to run the checksum.